# If $g(x) = 1-2s(1−\cos(x))−ic \sin(x)$, show that $|g(x)| \le 1$ iff $0\le c^2 \le 2s \le 1$.

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

**Question:** If 
$$g(x) = 1-2s(1−\cos(x))−ic \sin(x),$$ show that $|g(x)| \le 1$ iff $0\le c^2 \le 2s \le 1$.

**My attempt:** Ugh I  am completely stuck, here. I've tried finding $|g(x)|^2$, which is:

$$|g(x)|^2 = (1-2s(1-\cos(x)))^2 + c^2\sin^2(x),$$

but that first square is not coming out pretty. I would really appreciate some hints - I know there is a trig identity or a trick or something that I am missing, but I can't see it!

Answer (score 0):

Expanding:

$$|g(x)|^2 = 1 + (2s)^2(1 - \cos x)^2 - 4s(1 - \cos x) + c^2 \sin^2 x \\ \le 1 + (2s)(1 - \cos x)^2 - 4s(1 - \cos x) + 2s \sin^2x \\ = 1 $$

where I used $c^2 \le 2s$ and $(2s)^2 \le 2s$ since $ 0\le 2s\le1$

Comment: Ah, I see, so this is the "if" part, but I am also stuck on the "only if" part: $|g(x)|> 1$ if $0 \le c^2 \le 2s \le 1$, do you have any insights on that part?

Comment: @poppy3345 what I did was the "only if" part. It remains to show that if $|g(x)| \le 1$ for all $x$, then $0 \le c^2 \le 2s \le 1$, or that if the chain of inequalities doesn't hold then **there exists** $x$ such that $|g(x)| > 1$. I'll give it a thought